# PowerPoint VBA: which command (or a set of commands) would create ppt frames out of my .jpg pictures?

Tags: vba, image, powerpoint, paste, frames

I have a few .jpg files in C:\my_folder

Here are their names: pic_1.jpg , pic_2.jpg , pic_3.jpg , pic_4.jpg , pic_5.jpg .

What command or a group of commands in Power Point VBA should I use in order to be able to automatically create several frames in PowerPoint so that each frame would contain one picture?

Comment: what do you mean "frame"? does that mean an outline effect on a picture? one slide per picture? all pictures on one slide? also, are you looking to have powerpoint retrieve the pictures from your folder and insert them or...?

Comment: Yes, Otaku, I am sorry for my poor wording. Yes, I mean a "slide" by a "frame". Yes, I want PowerPoint to create slides (just as many as the pictures that I have), then retrieve the pictures from my folder, and insert each picture into each slide. One slide - one picture

Comment: Alivo's answer below is on the right track for a programmatic solution, although from within PowerPoint you would use VBA instead of VBScript and in .NET/VSTO you could use C# or VB.NET. But this is possible without programming as well - just use the "Photo Album" feature to select your folder/pictures and then push OK. One slide will be created for each picture. In PowerPoint 2007/2010 this is available from the Ribbon's Insert tab.

Comment: @Otaku: Thanks. Can you, please, give me a clue on how I could do it in VBA?  I created a macro out of his script, but it doesn't work. My PowerPoint is 2003 - maybe that's why his macro doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This VBScript creates a new PowerPoint presentation and adds two slides to it, each with a picture.  You will need to adjust the picture's location and size to suit your taste.  Also you'll need to utilize the Scripting.FileScriptingObject to enumerate your images if you want to automatically grab whatever pictures exist in a directory for embedding into the presentation.  If you want your script can also save the presentation by calling `pptPresentation.SaveAs` after your slides are generated.

The MSDN documentation is located at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff746873.aspx.

```
Dim pptDoc
Dim pptPresentation
Dim pptSlide

Set pptDoc = WScript.CreateObject( "PowerPoint.Application" )
pptDoc.Visible = True
Set pptPresentation = pptDoc.Presentations.Add( True )

' Add a new slide with a blank layout to the end of the Slides collection
' 12 = ppLayoutBlank
Set pptSlide = pptPresentation.Slides.Add( pptPresentation.Slides.Count + 1, 12 )

' Add a picture into the slide, saving the picture into the PowerPoint document
' 10, 10 are the Left and Top coordinates respectively
pptSlide.Shapes.AddPicture "c:\FullPath\1.JPG", False, True, 10, 10

' Add another slide with a picture
Set pptSlide = pptPresentation.Slides.Add( pptPresentation.Slides.Count + 1, 12 )
pptSlide.Shapes.AddPicture "c:\FullPath\2.jpg", False, True, 10, 10
```

Comment: @Avilo: Thanks for your time, but when I created a macro in PowerPoint with your script in Visual Basic Macro editor window, it didn't work. Not only pictures are not retrieved from my folder, but even new slides are not created. What an I missing here?

Comment: Sorry, this script runs outside of PowerPoint.  I hadn't realized you were writing a PowerPoint VBA macro.  If you place the code I posted into a VBS file (ex. CreatePresentation.vbs) and run that it will work.

Comment: "I hadn't realized you were writing a PowerPoint VBA macro" - My fault, sorry. I should have said that right away. Can I simply place your code in a .txt file and then, having changed its extension from .txt to .vbs, run it somehow? Do I need to have some special software previously installed om my computer in order to run .vbs files? I am sorry I know nothing about VBScripting.

Comment: Yes, you have it right.  VBS files can be run by Windows without any additional software.

Comment: Thanks! I just run your script and it does create an application and it does retrieve my pictures!!! (I have multiplied the last "add-another-slide" paragraph in your script (the last paragraph) three times - changing the full path each time for each picture - thus, hoping to create three different slides with three different pics). But for some reason it creates only one slide and puts all three of my pictures into that one slide. Why is it so? Also, is there any way to make a loop in your script?

Comment: Did you copy both lines, to call Slides.Add and Shapes.AddPicture? It sounds like you are missing the Slides.Add call.  As for looping across the files in a directory, see my second answer that I just posted for you. The FileSystemObject code can be used in the VBS script in a similar manner.

Comment: Aaah! My fault again. Yes, you are right - I made a mistake while copying your script. It works really well now. WOW, having looked through your second answer, I found that VBA seems to be even more complicated than VBS. I kind of like VBSscript more now :) and am about to research how to make loops in it. Thanks for introducing me to this language (even though it wasn't your original intention :) ) and thank you also for your valuable answeres here.

Comment: Glad to be of help!  As for the differences, VBA is based on VBScript so loops in both will be the same.  You can take the FSO code from the VBA answer and use it in the VBS to generate slides from all of your picture files.

Answer (score 4):

As the previous answer was specific to VBS scripting, here is a version for embedding into PowerPoint as a VBA macro.  This was created with PowerPoint 2010.

This has the directory hard-coded so it's an exercise for the reader to prompt for a directory name to scan.

```
Sub CreatePictureSlideshow( )
  Dim presentation
  Dim layout
  Dim slide

  Dim FSO
  Dim folder
  Dim file
  Dim folderName

  ' Set this to point at the folder you wish to import JPGs from
  ' Note: make sure this ends with a backslash \
  folderName = "c:\somedirectory\"

  ' Delete all slides and setup variables
  Set presentation = Application.ActivePresentation
  If presentation.Slides.count > 0 Then
     presentation.Slides.Range.Delete
  End If
  Set layout = Application.ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(1)
  Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

  ' Retrieve the folder's file listing and process each file
  Set folder = FSO.GetFolder(folderName)
  For Each file In folder.Files

     ' Filter to only process JPG images
     If LCase(Mid(file.Name, Len(file.Name) - 3, 4)) = ".jpg" Then

        ' Create the new slide and delete any pre-existing contents
        Set slide = presentation.Slides.AddSlide(presentation.Slides.count + 1, layout)
        While slide.Shapes.count > 0
          slide.Shapes(1).Delete
        Wend

        ' Add the picture
        slide.Shapes.AddPicture folderName + file.Name, False, True, 10, 10

        ' Optional: create a textbox with the filename on the slide for reference
        '   Dim textBox
        '   Set textBox = slide.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 10, 10, 200, 200)
        '   textBox.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = file.Name
     End If
  Next

End Sub
```