# Is there a way to read images from a folder and save it in powerpoint

Tags: image, matlab, save

I have approx. 100 images , I want to read those images, do the resizing and save it in a power point using matlab, Is it way to save those images in a power point giving title to each slide.
I am reading images using this code:

```
for i = 1:numel(pngfiles)
   im{i} = imread(pngfiles{i});
  imrgb{i} = rgb2gray(im{i});
   imrgb_z{i} = imrgb{i}(160:350,280:450);
end
```

Comment: I don't believe MATLAB has direct integration with PowerPoint, but you could definitely write a C# or C++ code, which MATLAB could call, that would then, add it to PowerPoint. At that point though, you might as well do all of the resizing in C# or C++

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that the best approach would be to use a VBA script inside Powerpoint, rather than manipulating ppt from Matlab. The steps would be

1. Create your list of images in a folder - using a sensible naming scheme
2. Open Powerpoint; go to the VBA editor (Alt-F11) and add a module with the following lines of code in it (note - this is taken straight from https://stackoverflow.com/a/5038907/1967396 with minimal edits):

-

```
Sub CreatePictureSlideshow( )
  Dim presentation
  Dim layout
  Dim slide

  Dim FSO
  Dim folder
  Dim file
  Dim folderName
  Dim fileType

  ' Set this to point at the folder you wish to import JPGs from
  ' Note: make sure this ends with a backslash \
  fileType = ".jpg"                ' <<< change this to the type you want
  folderName = "c:\somedirectory\" ' <<< change this to the directory you want

  ' setup variables
  Set presentation = Application.ActivePresentation
  ' choose the layout you want: e.g. if the title needs a particular format
  Set layout = Application.ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(1) 
  Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

  ' Retrieve the folder's file listing and process each file
  Set folder = FSO.GetFolder(folderName)
  For Each file In folder.Files

     ' Filter to only process JPG images
     If LCase(Right(file.Name), 4)) = fileType Then

        ' Create the new slide and delete any pre-existing contents
        Set slide = presentation.Slides.AddSlide(presentation.Slides.count + 1, layout)
        While slide.Shapes.count > 0
          slide.Shapes(1).Delete  ' <<< You might not want to do this is you want to keep the title placeholder
        Wend

        ' Add the picture
        slide.Shapes.AddPicture folderName + file.Name, False, True, 10, 10


        ' Optional: create a textbox with the filename on the slide for reference
        ' alternatively, add text to the title shape

        Dim textBox
        Set textBox = slide.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 10, 10, 200, 200)
        textBox.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = file.Name ' <<< or whatever "title" you wanted
     End If
  Next

End Sub
```

You can modify this further to get the title in the format you want, etc.

Comment: in my point of view, it is much easier to use only matlab, because you dont need to call another script, macro etc. Well, at least if you know the basics of matlab. you still got +1, because of using the "native" language of MS-Office, what doesn't complicate things :)

Comment: @LuciusDomitiusAhenobarbus thanks for the comment. Note - I work in a mixed platform environment, and the COM method only works in Windows. For me - Matlab on Linux, PPT on Mac - using VBA is the most sensible option...

Answer (score 2):

you could try this:

[Is there an example of using MATLAB to create PowerPoint slides?](http://www.mathworks.de/support/solutions/en/data/1-3RHM2O/)

For example:

```
% before the following, you have to create the ppt as explained, see link above!
% I prefer using some name instead of i or j
for img_ind = 1:numel(pngfiles)
    % this depends on the ppt-version (see link above)-> here for 2007 and higher
    mySlide = Presentation.Slides.Add(1,'ppLayoutBlank')
    % Note: Change the image file full path names to where you save them
    Image1 = mySlide.Shapes.AddPicture('<full path>\name_of_image(img_ind).png','msoFalse','msoTrue',100,20,500,500)      
end
% then you have to save it, see link above!
```

In your case, I guess you have to save the image first as shown in the example:

```
print('-dpng','-r150','<full path>\test1.png')
```

**edit**

This will only work when using Matlab on Windows, because COM is needed. See comments on Floris answer!

Comment: Hi lucius ,thanks, I saw that example, But I have around 100 images and I cant add individually, I wanted to do it a loop.Is it posiible .I am kind of new at this.

Comment: thanks,but I couldn't get it to work,images are in an array " im{i}",print('-dpng','-r150','test{i}.png');blankSlide = Presentation.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts.Item(i);Slide(i)= presentation.Slides.AddSlide(i,blankSlide);
 Image{i} = Slide(i).Shapes.AddPicture('C:\Users\Ankit Gupta\Desktop\Rotatation\im{i}.png','msoFalse','msoTrue',100,20,500,500)    end
Presentation.SaveAs('C:\Users\Ankit Gupta\Desktop\Rotatation\ExamplePresentation.ppt') error " Error using Interface.91493475_5A91_11CF_8700_00AA0060263B/AddPicture
Invoke Error, Dispatch Exception:Description: The specified file wasn't found."

Comment: Well, you have to use a string, if your path is the same and im{i} is the name (without the extension) you can use it like this: Image{i} = Slide(i).Shapes.AddPicture(['C:\Users\Ankit Gupta\Desktop\Rotatation\' im{i} '.png'],'msoFalse','msoTrue',100,20,500,500);

Answer (score 1):

Coming late to this party:  Here's a "Matlab Pick of the Week"  tool:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30124-smart-powerpoint-exporter

Take note of some of the comments at that page, as apparently the tool has not been updated in a few years.